# When subtracting two quantities in the value property of textedit the result is incorrect

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code, very simple

```
private void precio1frm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        Costo.Value = precio1frm.Value - Costo.Value;
    }
```

What you have to do is when pressing a key subtract two amounts, the value field is supposed to be decimal, that is, it can do the subtraction, but if I put 50-50 for some reason it gives me -45 as a result

Comment: It sounds like the ```precio1frm``` value is being read as 5 and not 50 for some reason. You haven't really given enough information or context for me to say much more.

Comment: Guess: you may have something like `5,0` where `,` is supposed to be a thousand delimiter (which is ignored and the value is `50`) but actually a decimal delimiter and the value is `5.0 == 5`

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint you'll see that you're subtracting 50-5, likely because you're not picking up trailing zero's properly.  Perhaps there is a max character of one digit on costo.value, or perhaps you're not properly converting it to a decimal type before the math hits.

There's nothing useful in the code to diagnose your problem.  Code related to setting the values would be best.